# xcode swift Thread 1: signal SIGABRT/display url data from retrieved website info

Tags: json, swift, xcode, xcode9, sigabrt

I have 2 questions.
1. I keep getting signal SIGABRT and I don't know the issue. There questions didn't help. Project below!
2. When I get data from a website(mine) how would I display it in my table? Thanks.

Download: https://ufile.io/2sso0

Comment: Instead of putting up a download link for your project just paste in here.  Nobody wants to download some file from an unknown person.  Also, showing the full error would be helpful.

Comment: Then how do I paste the storyboard stuff?(UI, View Controllers, etc.)

Comment: Just include the relevant code.  We don't need to see your entire project - just the part that is crashing, and the context around that line.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you get is when something isn't hooked up properly, like an outlet. Do you have some sort of outlet that you're not 100% sure works? If so, delete and add it again. Also something that I do a lot when I get this issue is to right click(two finger click) on the yellow circle on your view controller. Then if there's a yellow triangle, I click on the x and delete it. That fixes it for me.

Comment: it give me an error.
"Couldn't compile connection: <IBCocoaTouchOutletConnection: 0x7f84f26acf10 (OpV-i2-4rx)  source=<IBProxyObject: 0x7f84f26acb00 (vO5-VV-ua0) 'Placeholder for UIStoryboardPopoverPresentationSegueTemplate with OID 1zg-r5-2an'>  property=anchorView  destination=<IBUIButton: 0x7f84f26a4070 (D9z-yE-rEt) 'Anchor View'>>"

Comment: When you tried to double click on the view controller?

Comment: There were 2 yellow triangles, i deleted them and got that error.

Comment: If you google the topic there are other people that have had this and they will probably be able to offer more suggestions. That's all I can think of - but try this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23005369/popover-segue-not-working